# Can I combine several select queries in .net so they are returned in 1 batch?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to execute several select sql queries through 1 connection to the database (SQL Server). The queries will contain different tables data so it must not done using sql.

Basically I want to do that follwoing

```
select * from Table1
Go
Select * from Table2
Go
Select * from Table3
```

then send this query to the database and then I want to result to be returned in one hit, so I can then read the data using 3 datareaders.

Is this possible using c# and sqlserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GO is not a SQL statement. So you must send to the server the 3 queries as a single batch:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
@"select * from Table1;
select * from Table2;
select * from Table3;", connection);
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
     //read results from Table1
   };
   rdr.NextResult();
   while(rdr.Read())
   {
    //read results from Table2
   }
   rdr.NextResult();
   while(rdr.Read())
   {
     //read results from Table3
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Multiple Active Result Sets: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/database/article.php/c8715

Comment: IT shoudl use SqlDataReader.NextResult. MARS is for issuing queries *while* iterating a result, is a different scenarion.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [SqlDataReader.NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult%28classic%29.aspx)?