# Can several Inserts be executed using SqlDataReader.NextResult() the same way several Selects can be?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to execute several inserts at the smame batch to speed up the program.
Is it possible to  do the following?

```
Insert Into Table1 (a) Values (@a);
Insert Into Table2 (b) Values (@b);
Insert Into Table3 (c) Values (@c);
```

and if it's possible then how should I pass the parameters to the SQL Parameters?

Basically I want to do something like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512254/can-i-combine-several-select-queries-in-net-so-they-are-returned-in-1-batch) but for `Insert` instead of `Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example:

```
var sql = StringBuilder();

sql.Append "Insert Table1(a)"
sql.AppendFormat "\nSelect @a"
sql.AppendFormat "\nUnion All Select @b"
sql.AppendFormat "\nUnion All Select @b"
sql.AppendFormat "\nUnion All Select @c"
...

// Set your paramters values
var cmd = new SqlCommand( sql.ToString() );
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@b", aValue));
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@b", bValue));
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c", cValue));
...

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The line breaks are not necessary. They are only there so the output is nicely formatted. If you put your values into a hashtable, you could even do it in a loop like so:

```
var values = new Hashtable();
values.Add("a", avalue);
values.Add("b", bvalue);
values.Add("c", cvalue);
...


var sql = StringBuilder();
var cmd = new SqlCommand();

foreach( var value in values )
{
    if (sql.Length == 0)
    {
        sql.Append "Insert Table1(columnName)"
        sql.AppendFormat "\nSelect @" + value.Key   
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + value.Key, value.Value));
    }
    else
    {
        sql.AppendFormat "\nUnion All Select @" + value.Key
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + value.Key, value.Value));
    }
}

cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert Into Table1 (a) Values (@a);Insert Into Table2 (b Values (@b);Insert Into Table3 (c) Values (@c);", connection);

// Set your paramters values
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@a", aValue));
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@b", bValue));
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c", cValue));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: basically it's correct, im not sure wheter you need to add a "go" between them?